# does anyone know _UIApplicationDidRemoveDeactivationReasonNotification?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

when ever a _UIApplicationDidRemoveDeactivationReasonNotification notification is posted
(which is an apple private NSNotification) it holds a NSNumber in it's userInfo,
does anyone know, what does each number mean?

the key is _UIApplicationDeactivationReasonUserInfoKey

all I know so far number 5 means app resigned active for InAppPurchase-verification
(which is an OS message and makes your app inactive until user clicks 'Cancel' or 'Buy')

Comment: Why do you need to know this? Messing with private Apple APIs is a surefire way to get your app rejected when you submit to the app store.

Comment: you're not helping, no offense.

Comment: I find that often people think there is no other way to do something when in fact there is.  Especially when thinking about messing with Apple private notifications and APIs.  It is possible that there is an official and documented way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: there are many ways your app can get interrupted, I want to know what to do for each one: -receiving phone call, -pressing home button, -doubletap home button. -pressing power button.... each f-ing one has a different deactivation/delays

Comment: So you have somehow found a situation where the various application delegate methods for getting notified when you resign/become active, when you enter the background/foreground, when you are about to be terminated and when you should save or load your state are insufficient?  If you have, it would be helpful for me and others to know.

Answer (score 2):

So I needed this and I got a few values decoded.

I am looking at another similar notification `_UIApplicationWillAddDeactivationReasonNotification`
with same value key `_UIApplicationDeactivationReasonUserInfoKey`

here they are (for ios6/7):

```
// notification/control center overlay
kDeactivationReasonControlOverlay = 1,
// double tapped for the task manager mode
kDeactivationReasonTaskManager = 2,
// app is going inactive, eg: locked, enter background, power off screen, phone call, voice control (not siri)
kDeactivationReasonLockScreen = 3,
// system alerts, eg: privacy permissions, IAP dialogs
kDeactivationReasonSystemAlert = 5,
// siri overlay
kDeactivationReasonSiriOverlay = 6,
```

However I don't have a test case which i can reproduce 4.
And I don't know if 0 or values above 6 are valid values, if anyone knows please comment!